# AttributeError: 'FastAPI' object has no attribute 'logger'

Tags: python, fastapi

I am Migrating my code from Python flask to Fast-API. I am facing an issue in adding loggers to fast API, It will display

> "AttributeError: 'FastAPI' object has no attribute 'logger'"

Please refer the code for more info

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
import uvicorn
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import logging

app = FastAPI()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d] %(levelname)s [%(thread)d] - %(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    handler = RotatingFileHandler('/log/abc.log', backupCount=0)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    app.logger.info('****************** Starting Server *****************') # "AttributeError: 'FastAPI' object has no attribute 'logger'"
    uvicorn.run()
```

Comment: `FastAPI` class does not have a member/attribute named `logger`.  So, to use the logger provided by fastapi, import fastapi.logger and use it.

Answer (score 11):

You should import the fastapi logger and then manipulate it. `from fastapi.logger import logger`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.logger import logger as fastapi_logger
import uvicorn
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import logging

app = FastAPI()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "[%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d] %(levelname)s [%(thread)d] - %(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    handler = RotatingFileHandler('/log/abc.log', backupCount=0)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
    fastapi_logger.addHandler(handler)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    fastapi_logger.info('****************** Starting Server *****************')
    uvicorn.run()
```

Comment: is this logger should log any error? I copypasted this code into `main.py`, added `1/0` to my code, and nothing happened, it's just creating a file for me, but not writing into it